# Writing a netcdf4 file is 6-times slower than writing a netcdf3_classic file and the file is 8-times as big?

Tags: file-io, netcdf

I am using the netCDF4 library in python and just came across the issue stated in the title. At first I was blaming groups for this, but it turns out that it is a difference between the NETCDF4 and NETCDF3_CLASSIC formats (edit: and it appears related to our Linux installation of the netcdf libraries).

In the program below, I am creating a simple time series netcdf file of the same data in 2 different ways: 1) as NETCDF3_CLASSIC file, 2) as NETCDF4 flat file (creating groups in the netcdf4 file doesn't make much of a difference). What I find with a simple timing and the ls command is:

```
1) NETCDF3          1.3483 seconds      1922704 bytes
2) NETCDF4 flat     8.5920 seconds     15178689 bytes
```

It's exactly the same routine which creates 1) and 2), the only difference is the format argument in the netCDF4.Dataset method. Is this a bug or a feature?

Thanks, Martin

Edit: I have now found that this must have something to do with our local installation of the netcdf library on a Linux computer. When I use the program version below (trimmed down to the essentials) on my Windows laptop, I get similar file sizes, and netcdf4 is actually almost 2-times as fast as netcdf3! When I run the same program on our linux system, I can reproduce the old results. Thus, this question is apparently not related to python.

Sorry for the confusion.

New code:

```
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import netCDF4 as nc


def write_to_netcdf_single(filename, data, series_info, format='NETCDF4'):
    vname = 'testvar'
    t0 = dt.datetime.now()
    with nc.Dataset(filename, "w", format=format) as f:
        # define dimensions and variables
        dim = f.createDimension('time', None)
        time = f.createVariable('time', 'f8', ('time',))
        time.units = "days since 1900-01-01 00:00:00"
        time.calendar = "gregorian"
        param = f.createVariable(vname, 'f4', ('time',))
        param.units = "kg"
        # define global attributes
        for k, v in sorted(series_info.items()):
            setattr(f, k, v)
        # store data values
        time[:] = nc.date2num(data.time, units=time.units, calendar=time.calendar)
        param[:] = data.value
    t1 = dt.datetime.now()
    print "Writing file %s took %10.4f seconds." % (filename, (t1-t0).total_seconds())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # create an array with 1 mio values and datetime instances
    time = np.array([dt.datetime(2000,1,1)+dt.timedelta(hours=v) for v in range(1000000)])
    values = np.arange(0., 1000000.)
    data = np.array(zip(time, values), dtype=[('time', dt.datetime), ('value', 'f4')])                                                                                       
    data = data.view(np.recarray)
    series_info = {'attr1':'dummy', 'attr2':'dummy2'}
    filename = "testnc4.nc"
    write_to_netcdf_single(filename, data, series_info)
    filename = "testnc3.nc"
    write_to_netcdf_single(filename, data, series_info, format='NETCDF3_CLASSIC')
```

[old code deleted because it had too much unnecessary stuff]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question is unlikely to help others as it appears to be a site-specific problem related to the interplay between netcdf libraries and the python netCDF4 module.

Answer (score 1):

The two file formats do have different characteristics.  the classic file format was dead simple (well, more simple than the new format: http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf/Classic-Format-Spec.html#Classic-Format-Spec ):  A small header described all the data, and then (since you have 3 record variables) the 3 record variables get interleaved.

nice and simple, but you only get one UNLIMITED dimension, there's no facility for parallel I/O, and no way to manage data into groups.

Enter the new HDF5-based back-end, introduced in NetCDF-4.

In exchange for new features,  more flexibility, and fewer restrictions on file and variable size, you have to pay a bit of a price.  For large datasets, the costs are amortized, but your variables are (relatively speaking) kind of small.

I think the file size discrepancy is exacerbated by your use of record variables.  in order to support arrays grow-able in N dimensions, there is more metadata associated with each record entry in the Netcdf-4 format.

HDF5 uses the "reader makes right" convention, too.  classic NetCDF says "all data will be big-endian", but HDF5 encodes a bit of information about how the data was stored.  If the reader process is the same architecture as the writer process (which is common, as it would be on your laptop or if restarting from a simulation checkpoint), then no conversion need be conducted.

Comment: I can see this, yet I am still puzzled what is going on here. Especially, since I am now getting the OPPOSITE result when I try to trim down the program to the essentials so that everyone can run it. The edited code above returns 4 secs for the netcdf3 and 2.5 secs for netcdf4 version, respectively. And the file sizes are approximately similar. So there must be something else going on in my original code...

Comment: so you've changed nearly everything: your code is simpler, your operating system is different, and the associated software stack is undoubtedly configured differently.  It's possible windows does a better job caching the hdf5 accesses?  or it is exposing a file system block size that really slows down serial netcdf?